# Nokogiri Xpath Double Looping

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, scraper

What I'm trying to do is pul the code block that contains the td with the class default. This works perfectly fine. But then I need to sort out the different parts of the code block. When I try to do this with the second xpath call what it does is each time it prints all the comheads in each of the blocks

```
   def HeaderProcessor(doc)         
        doc.xpath("//td[@class='default']").each do |block|             
            puts block.xpath("//span[@class='comhead']").text
        end
    end
```

When I just print out block each block prints out once and contains the comment header and the comment. When I try to run the xpath it prints out EVERY comhead found in doc and seems to be ignoring the block variable.

Any ideas on how I can make this work? What am I miss understanding about xpath?

UPDATE:

```
<td class="default">
<div style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:-10px; ">
<span class="comhead">
#some data        
</span></div>
<br><span class="comment"><font color="#000000">#some more data</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling Nokogiri to search from the root when you say `//span[@class='comhead']`, you just want `*/span[@class='comhead']`:

```
doc.xpath("//td[@class='default']").each do |block|
    block.xpath("*/span[@class='comhead']").each do |span|
        puts span.text
    end
end
```

or even just this:

```
doc.xpath('//td[@class="default"]/*/span[@class="comhead"]').each do |span|
    puts span.text
end
```

if you don't need to do anything with the `<td>` elements.

Comment: A few things don't make sense to me: 1. If I am using the block variable, how come it can access all the other spans in the other blocks. I'm using block as the new doc basically. 2. When I try your first example it gives me a bunch of empty lines and it nothing else. When I try your second example, it doesn't output anything. I've added a simplified version of the actual HTML to my original question. I hope that is helpful.

Comment: @NoahClark: The first and second examples didn't work because you had extra elements inside your `<td>` that I didn't know about, I've updated it to account for the new structure. Your `block` is still attached to `doc` so it knows where the root is so `//...` starts again at `doc`; this may or may not be correct but that's what it is doing.

Comment: Okay, that makes perfect sense. Thanks so much!